# Why does a NSAttributedString, drawn inside a NSRulerView, scroll with the NSTextView, but a NSRect drawn in it doesn't?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextview

I try to have a NSTextView, with line numbers. The background of the line numbers should have another color, when the selection of the TextView is in this line. It works very well with this code (I found it on https://github.com/daizhirui/macOS-Development/tree/master/LineNumberView/line-number-text-view-master and added the code for the background):

```
/// Defines the width of the gutter view.
fileprivate let GUTTER_WIDTH: CGFloat = 40    


/// Adds line numbers to a NSTextField.
class LineNumberGutter: NSRulerView {

    /// Holds the background color.
    internal var backgroundColor: NSColor {
        didSet {
            self.needsDisplay = true
        }
    }

    /// Holds the text color.
    internal var foregroundColor: NSColor {
        didSet {
            self.needsDisplay = true
        }
    }

    ///  Initializes a LineNumberGutter with the given attributes.
    ///
    ///  - parameter textView:        NSTextView to attach the LineNumberGutter to.
    ///  - parameter foregroundColor: Defines the foreground color.
    ///  - parameter backgroundColor: Defines the background color.
    ///
    ///  - returns: An initialized LineNumberGutter object.
    init(withTextView textView: NSTextView, foregroundColor: NSColor, backgroundColor: NSColor) {
        // Set the color preferences.
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        self.foregroundColor = foregroundColor

        // Make sure everything's set up properly before initializing properties.
        super.init(scrollView: textView.enclosingScrollView, orientation: .verticalRuler)

        // Set the rulers clientView to the supplied textview.
        self.clientView = textView
        // Define the ruler's width.
        self.ruleThickness = GUTTER_WIDTH
    }

    ///  Initializes a default LineNumberGutter, attached to the given textView.
    ///  Default foreground color: hsla(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
    ///  Default background color: hsla(0, 0, 0.95, 1);
    ///
    ///  - parameter textView: NSTextView to attach the LineNumberGutter to.
    ///
    ///  - returns: An initialized LineNumberGutter object.
    convenience init(withTextView textView: NSTextView) {
        let fg = NSColor(calibratedHue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 0, alpha: 1)
        let bg = NSColor(calibratedHue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 0, alpha: 1)
        // Call the designated initializer.
        self.init(withTextView: textView, foregroundColor: fg, backgroundColor: bg)
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    ///  Draws the line numbers.
    ///
    ///  - parameter rect: NSRect to draw the gutter view in.
    override func drawHashMarksAndLabels(in rect: NSRect) {
        // Set the current background color...
        self.backgroundColor.setFill()
        // ...and fill the given rect.
        rect.fill()

        // Unwrap the clientView, the layoutManager and the textContainer, since we'll
        // them sooner or later.
        guard let textView = self.clientView as? NSTextView, let layoutManager = textView.layoutManager, let textContainer = textView.textContainer else { return }

        let content = textView.string

        //I added the following lines
        let nsString = content as NSString
        let selectedRange = textView.selectedRange()

        var newlineCountBeforeSelection:Int?
        if selectedRange.location != NSNotFound {
            let textBeforeSelection = nsString.substring(to: selectedRange.location)
            newlineCountBeforeSelection = textBeforeSelection.countOccurrences(ofCharacter: "\n")
        }

        // Get the range of the currently visible glyphs.
        let visibleGlyphsRange = layoutManager.glyphRange(forBoundingRect: textView.visibleRect, in: textContainer)

        // Check how many lines are out of the current bounding rect.
        var lineNumber = 1
        do {
            // Define a regular expression to find line breaks.
            let newlineRegex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\n", options: [])
            // Check how many lines are out of view; From the glyph at index 0
            // to the first glyph in the visible rect.
            lineNumber += newlineRegex.numberOfMatches(in: content, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, visibleGlyphsRange.location))
        } catch {
            return
        }

        // Get the index of the first glyph in the visible rect, as starting point...
        var firstGlyphOfLineIndex = visibleGlyphsRange.location

        // ...then loop through all visible glyphs, line by line.
        while firstGlyphOfLineIndex < NSMaxRange(visibleGlyphsRange) {
            // Get the character range of the line we're currently in.
            let charRangeOfLine = (content as NSString).lineRange(for: NSRange(location: layoutManager.characterIndexForGlyph(at: firstGlyphOfLineIndex), length: 0))
            // Get the glyph range of the line we're currently in.
            let glyphRangeOfLine = layoutManager.glyphRange(forCharacterRange: charRangeOfLine, actualCharacterRange: nil)

            var firstGlyphOfRowIndex = firstGlyphOfLineIndex
            var lineWrapCount = 0

            // Loop through all rows (soft wraps) of the current line.
            while firstGlyphOfRowIndex < NSMaxRange(glyphRangeOfLine) {
                // The effective range of glyphs within the current line.
                var effectiveRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: 0)
                // Get the rect for the current line fragment.
                let lineRect = layoutManager.lineFragmentRect(forGlyphAt: firstGlyphOfRowIndex, effectiveRange: &effectiveRange, withoutAdditionalLayout: true)

                // Draw the current line number;
                // When lineWrapCount > 0 the current line spans multiple rows.
                if lineWrapCount == 0 {
                    //This lines draw the background
                    if let newlineCountBeforeSelection = newlineCountBeforeSelection, (lineNumber - 1) == newlineCountBeforeSelection {
                        let rect = NSRect(x: 0, y: lineRect.minY, width: GUTTER_WIDTH, height: lineRect.height)
                        NSColor.selectedBackground.setFill()
                        rect.fill()
                    }
                    self.drawLineNumber(num: lineNumber, atYPosition: lineRect.minY)
                } else {
                    break
                }

                // Move to the next row.
                firstGlyphOfRowIndex = NSMaxRange(effectiveRange)
                lineWrapCount += 1
            }

            // Move to the next line.
            firstGlyphOfLineIndex = NSMaxRange(glyphRangeOfLine)
            lineNumber += 1
        }

        // Draw another line number for the extra line fragment.
        if let _ = layoutManager.extraLineFragmentTextContainer {
            //This lines draw the background
            if let newlineCountBeforeSelection = newlineCountBeforeSelection, (lineNumber - 1) == newlineCountBeforeSelection {
                let rect = NSRect(x: 0, y: layoutManager.extraLineFragmentRect.minY, width: GUTTER_WIDTH, height: layoutManager.extraLineFragmentRect.height)
                NSColor.selectedBackground.setFill()
                rect.fill()
            }
            self.drawLineNumber(num: lineNumber, atYPosition: layoutManager.extraLineFragmentRect.minY)
        }
    }


    func drawLineNumber(num: Int, atYPosition yPos: CGFloat) {
        // Unwrap the text view.
        guard let textView = self.clientView as? NSTextView, let font = textView.font else { return }
        // Define attributes for the attributed string.
        let attrs = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: self.foregroundColor]
        // Define the attributed string.
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "\(num)", attributes: attrs)
        // Get the NSZeroPoint from the text view.
        let relativePoint = self.convert(NSPoint.zero, from: textView)
        // Calculate the x position, within the gutter.
        let xPosition = GUTTER_WIDTH - (attributedString.size().width + 5)
        // Draw the attributed string to the calculated point.
        attributedString.draw(at: NSPoint(x: xPosition, y: relativePoint.y + yPos - 4))
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: Line Numbers]

But if I scroll in the TextView, the line numbers, which are drawn with NSAttributedString.draw(at:) scroll together with the text, but the background doesn't scroll:

[image: Background Scroll]

How can I fix this?

Comment: `drawLineNumber` adds `relativePoint.y`.

Comment: Thank you so much...so stupid, that I overlook so often such simple things. Please provide an Answer, so I can accept it.